# Iterar expresión de DAX sobre rango de fechas (Power Bi)

Tags: powerbi, dax

Dispongo de una base de datos en la que nos interesan dos tablas: 'public incidencias' y Calendario:
[image: Las dos tablas de interés y su relación]

Como se puede ver en la imagen, ambas están relacionadas por 'fecha_de_creacion' (fecha de creación de la incidencia).

Necesito crear una medida en DAX que me calcule para cada fecha del calendario la cantidad de incidencias que había sin cerrar. La siguiente medida me lo calcula correctamente para una fecha concreta:

```
Tareas Abiertas = 
    var fecha_n =  TODAY()
    return 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('public incidencias'[idincidencia]), 
        FILTER(
            'public incidencias',
            'public incidencias'[fecha_de_creacion] <= fecha_n 
            && ( 'public incidencias'[fecha_de_cierre] > fecha_n || 
            'public incidencias'[estado] <> "Cerrada")
        )
    )
```

Cómo podría hacer ese mismo cálculo para un rango de fechas. Es decir, en vez de tener fecha_n = TODAY() ,  que esta sea un rango de fechas que vayan desde la mínima fecha del **Calendario** hasta hoy, y como resultado tenga una tabla con cada fecha junto a su cantidad de tareas abiertas.

Comment: saca los filtros de fechas y deja solamente el de estado, luego pon en una tabla "Tareas Abiertas" y fecha_de_creacion

Comment: es más, podrías hacer todo con el objeto tabla sin cálculos ni nada, solo poniendo la columna incidencias (opción recuento) y luego la columna fecha_de_creacion y en los filtros de objeto le agregas la columna estado y configuras distinto de "Cerrada"

Comment: Buenos días @LPZadkiel  , gracias por contestar. No sé muy bien si entiendo tu propuesta. El problema es que la columna 'estado' es el estado que tienen a día de hoy las tareas. Para calcular el número de tareas que había abiertas en una fecha 'n'  necesito sumar aquellas cuya fecha de creación es igual o menor a 'n' y su fecha de cierre es posterior a 'n' (o su estado actual es distinto de "Cerrada", ya que en este caso no tendría fecha_de_cierre)

Comment: te tienes que olvidar del "Mayor que x fecha" y "menor que y fecha" porque lo que quieres es un recuento por día, entonces, asumiendo que `fecha_de_creacion` tiene fecha y hora lo que tendrías que hacer es crear una columna que contenga solamente la fecha y de esta forma al colocar en un objeto tabla esta nueva columna fecha y la columna incidencias con "Recuento" o "Count" según el idioma, esto te va a sumar automáticamente la cantidad de incidencias por día